# How can I extract and remove a string? So I can have similar expressions match 1 time instead of multiple times

Tags: r, string, stringr

**Problem description:** I'm currently extracting names from a book series. Many characters will go by nicknames, parts of names, or titles. I have a list of names that I'm using as a pattern on all of the data. The problem is that I'm getting multiple matches for full names and the parts of names. There are a total of 3000 names and variations of names that I'm running through a lot of text. The names are currently extracted in order from longest strings to shortest.

**Question:**

How can I ensure that after a pattern is extracted, that whatever text it matches is then removed from the string?

**What I get:**

```
str_extract("Mr Bean and friends", pattern = fixed(c("Mr Bean", "Bean", "Mr")))  
[1] "Mr Bean" "Bean"    "Mr"
```

**What I want:** (I know that I can't achieve this only using str_extract() or one line of code)

```
str_extract("Mr Bean and friends", pattern = fixed (c("Mr Bean", "Bean", "Mr")))  
[1] "Mr Bean" NA NA
```

Comment: Using `str_extract("Mr Bean and friends", pattern = "Mr Bean|Bean|Mr")` would return just "Mr Bean". Would that be a solution for your case?

Comment: The problem with that is that there are multiple things I want to match in a single string, along with multiple things that I don't want to match. That will work for all variations of Mr. Bean, but if I add in Mrs Bean, then I also want it to match her name which won't work if I compile the name list into one giant regex filled with "|"s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to update recursively.  As we want an output `vector` of `length` 'n' equal to the `length` of `pattern` `vector`, create an output vector to store the values, then update the initial string after execution of each 'pattern' by removing the 'pattern' from the string and updating it

```
library(stringr)
for(i in seq_along(pat))  {
      out[i] <- str_extract(str1, pattern = fixed(pat[i]))
      str1 <- str_remove(str1, pat[i])
 }
out
#[1] "Mr Bean" NA        NA
```

---

Or the same method with `vapply` and updating the initial string with `<<-`

```
unname(vapply(pat, function(p) {
   out <- str_extract(str1, p)
   str1 <<- str_remove(str1, p)
   out}, character(1)))
#[1] "Mr Bean" NA        NA
```

#### data

```
# initialize an output vector
out <- character(length(pat))
# pattern vector
pat <- c("Mr Bean", "Bean", "Mr")
# initial string
str1 <- "Mr Bean and friends"
str2 <- str1
```

Comment: This assumes that the strings are ordered in such a way that if `a` is a substring of `b` that `a` is not before `b`.

Comment: The strings are ordered in such a way, the solution works well, the only issue is that this solution is computationally intensive, but I've already accepted that I'll have to run some code for a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Would using [pmatch](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pmatch.html) work?

```
my_string <- "Mr Bean and friends"
my_pattern <- c("Mr Bean", "Bean", "Mr")

out <- my_pattern[pmatch(my_pattern,my_string)]
out
[1] "Mr Bean" NA        NA
```